# PayEx_Online_Payment extension not working in magento 1.5.1.0,is there any solution?

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.5.1.0.Client needs payex for payment process.I installed PayEx_Online_Payment but there is no link in admin panel after installing it.I have searched alot on internet and found no answer.
Kindly help me as I need it to be configured today.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much about this specific extension, I would recommend following these steps after installing any extension.

- Refresh all cache - Admin->System->Cache Management
- Log out and then back in.

I would guess the module's configuration is set under Admin->System->Configuration then it may have its own option under the sales tab on the left, or you may have to select Payment Methods to configure.

If you can't find any mention of the module there then check under Admin->System->Configuration->Advanced and then make sure the module has an entry in the list shown and that it is enabled.

Comment: I had done all this things even before writing question here.Its very difficult in magento to correct payex module.

Comment: If you have compilation enabled, then you may need to recompile. Try `php -f shell/compiler.php compile` on the command line or go to System->Tools->Compilation and then 'Run Compilation Process'.

Answer (score 0):

There is one extension of payex under magento gallery. I think its :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Ravi+Singh/extension/7816/payex_online_payment_method

I had taken this and its supporting Magento fully.